# Есть ли в Boost парсер математических выражений?

Tags: c++, boost

Чтобы отправить строку с выражением с переменными и получить результат.

Comment: Proto, metaparse, spirit.

Comment: Spirit однозначно может)) на гите тьма всего по этой теме

Comment: @Maggot, просто я валенок криворукий, и не могу подключить ничего =) Постоянно какая-то фигня.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Ну ничего, все такими же были) никто еще не родился с навыками)))

Comment: Подскажите, где учить boost

Comment: @Lofectr. тут - https://www.boost.org/doc/